# TFS2013 (from Web) Team Room is not highlighting member names

Tags: tfs

When playing around with the TFS 2013 Team Rooms in the web browser I'm not finding that references to member names are highlighting like the documentation shows, are we missing a setting somewhere?

[MSDN Example](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/collaborate-in-the-team-room-vs.aspx).

When we do @Username we get just the plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user that you are directing the comment to is the one that gets to see the highlight.

You will not see the coloured highlight when someone else references you.

Answer (score 0):

The above MSDN example is for the Team Room web page. For Visual Studio you have to use the Team Rooms for Visual Studio 2013 extension that is based on Team Rooms API which is not public so don't expect to have the same functionality as in the web page

Comment: I am not sure that you understood the question.